# call initialize method in ngOnInit or constructor

Tags: angular, constructor, ngoninit

Im very new to Angular 4,

Can you tell me what is the different between call a method like initializeMyObj()
in constructor than ngOnInit in ts file?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major difference is that constructor is typescript construct whereas **ngOnInit** is life cycle hook of component and directive.

Constructor is used to initialize the component. At this time, **@Input** bound properties are not initialized.

On the other hand **ngOnInit** is called *once* after **constructor** and **ngOnChange**. At this time, the component is initialized and properties are bound.

```
@Component({
...
})
export class MyComp{
    @Input() someprop;
    constructor(){
        console.log(someprop); //undefined
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log(someprop); 
    }
}
```